# Pegar parametro da URL

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, mvc, imagem, view

Preciso de um código que quando eu clicar em cima da imagem, essa imagem vai abrir em uma nova guia. Até agora consegui fazer com que quando eu clicar em cima da minha imagem ela abre outra guia com o caminho da imagem na URL. Como faço para pegar esse caminho que está na URL e fazer aparecer a imagem na minha página, sendo que meu código está em CodeIgniter e em MVC. Essa imagem está salva no meu banco de dados.

O código que estou usando para abrir a imagem é:

```
  function abreFoto(){
                window.open('<?= base_url('ControllerL/verFoto' + $l->foto_caminho ,'_blank'); ?>');
            }
```

meu Controller:

```
public function verFoto($id) {
            $data['id'] = $id;
            $data['foto'] = $this->ML->getFoto($id);

        $this->load->view('ViewFoto', $data);
    }
```

meu Model:

```
public function getFoto($id) {
        $this->db->select('fots.foto_id, fots.foto_caminho, laus.Laudo_id');
        $this->db->from('fots');
        $this->db->where('laus.Laudo_id', $id);
        $q = $this->db->get();
        return $q->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Para pegar parâmetros da URL no Codeigniter, você utiliza:

```
$this->input->get('nome_do_parametro');
```

É possível pegar o parâmetro pelo segmento da URI também:

```
$this->uri->segment(3); // Onde segmento 1 = controller; 2 = Método; 3+ = Parâmetros
```

Espero que tenha ajudado